# Azure artifact feed ididentifier in azure pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-artifacts

When I try to push a nuget package to local Artifact feed using it's name the push fails saying:

```
error: Unable to load the service index for source 
https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/companyname/_packaging/MyFeed/nuget/v3/index.json.
error:   Response status code does not indicate success: 404 (Not Found - The feed with ID 'MyFeed' doesn't exist.
```

My configuration is:

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Publish nuget'
  inputs:
    command: 'push'
    nuGetFeedType: 'internal'
    packagesToPush: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/*.nupkg'
    publishVstsFeed: 'MyFeed'
```

Now if I add this block using the visual tools provided on the right when editing azure-pipelines.yaml it puts some identifier that looks like 'GUID/GUID' and using this one actually works. So I am wondering is there some configuration I am missing for the Pipeline or the Feed?

I checked and both Project and Project collection Build services has Contributor rights on the feed.

Answer (score 4):

For reference,

> the publishVstsFeed value should follow this pattern:
> `publishVstsFeed: '<projectName>/<feed>'`

https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/11258#issuecomment-633009958